# Modulo results in "Division by zero" error

Tags: php

I am using modulo operator as seen below, but when I run it reports a `Division by zero` error with assignment to `$new`. How can I fix this?

```
$per = 0.2;
$a = 20;
$new = $a % $per;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example, `$per` is a floating point number (0.2). The modulo operator only accepts two integer operands, per the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> Operands of modulo are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing. For floating-point modulo, see [`fmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php).

Since the operator only accepts integer operands, `$per` with value 0.2 is converted to 0, thus yielding the error. As suggested in the manual you may use [`fmod`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) as an alternative:

```
$new = fmod($a, $per);
```